# Issue with ActionLink in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I just write

```
Response.Write("<a href='/someurl'>Some Text</a>");
```

Instead of

```
Response.Write(Html.ActionLink(...));
```

This reason I am after this is because I am writing a Pagination ViewUserControl.  In the control I want it to show page numbers, next and previous pages etc.

When I use the following code

```
Response.Write(Html.ActionLink(page.ToString(), HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl, new { page = page }));
```

The link is written out as `http://localhost:61293/customers/customers/System.Web.Mvc.UrlParameter/page2` which is obviously incorrect.

`HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl == "/customers/"` in this example. I would have expected that the resultant Url was then `/customers/page2` as opposed to what is actually written out.

My routes are set up like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/page{page}", // URL with parameters
            new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                page = UrlParameter.Optional
            } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Where are you trying to do this and where do you want this link to get rendered? Why don't you want to use ActionLink? Why are you using Response.Write?

Comment: Thanks - I have updated question with the reasons why!

Comment: now that you have updated your question, you are saying that you are writing a view control. What exactly do you mean by this? Is it a class that derives from UserControl?

Comment: I use simply html instead of helper because in html code is easy to read and easy to know what i do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your update, you shouldn't be using `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` as the action of your `ActionLink`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505040(v=VS.90).aspx

```
public static string ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    object routeValues
)
```

As you can see, `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` will not match any of your actions. Try writing:

```
Html.ActionLink(page.ToString(), 
    "TheNameOfTheActionMethod", 
    new { page = page });
```

Comment: I don't see how this is preferable over `<%= Html.ActionLink("my link", "someaction") %>`.

Comment: me neither, but it'll get you the url

Comment: I guess if you don't like passing in the html attributes or you want it to look more like HTML. I usually use `ActionLink` but to each its own.

Comment: @hunter, I think that the OP needs to explain what he is trying to do. Also the third example you've added with `Response.Write`, what a tag soup, I don't have words to describe it :-)

Comment: @Darin, agreed. Going off of his title I think this is what he's asking for.

Comment: I think the last example needs to be UrlHelper.Action(...)

Comment: @Ferruccio - depends where it's called from

Comment: @hunter - where is Url? When I do a ctrl-. on it, VS wants to add 'using System.Security.Policy'. Anyway I upvoted the answer. I don't know if it helped the op, but it helped me :-)

Comment: I want this `ViewUserControl` to work with any controller / action combo I have hence trying to use the RawUrl as a base.

Comment: If I were you I would pass in the action to the ViewUserControl in either a model object or in the ViewData rather than trying to pull it from the RawUrl. If you would like an example please post your ViewUserControl and I'll show you how it's done

Comment: @Ferruccio, that's in System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your routing set up improperly -- probably a parameter in the wrong place in one of your routes.  The reason I say this is because it appears that the ToString method of the UrlParameter class itself is being called, resulting in the name of the class being output.

Paging Route (from comments) -- this assumes that the "list" action is "index" and you don't want the index action to appear in the route.  Note that it inherits the controller from the current request and, since the action is by convention, you don't need to supply it. Completely untested.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Pager", // Route name
        "{controller}/page{page}", // URL with parameters
        new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            page = UrlParameter.Optional
        } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Used as:

```
 <%= Html.RouteLink( page, "Pager", new { page = page }, null ) %>
```

Comment: @Chris -- have you tried stripping off the slashes from the RawUrl? `RawUrl.Trim('/')`.

Comment: @Chris - the problem may be that you don't have an id parameter in a route where the id parameter would be required.  Try creating another route (I'll update my question with a sample) just for the pager without an id, then refer to it by name using the RouteLink extension.  It should come after the default route.

Answer (score 0):

```
Url.Action("ActionMethodName", new { page = i });
```

Answer (score 0):

Chris,

By reading your "clarifications" and comments above I think you just overcomplicate things around.

Most clear thing that is recognizable between the lines is that you want somewhat reusable widget showing you the paginable list of customers.

So why not just simply:

- Create `CustomerController`, and an `Index()` as an action to show list of customers
- Map routes `"customers"` and `"customers/page{page}"` to `CustomerController.Index()`
- Use `Html.RenderAction("Index", "Customer", new {page = page})` wherever you need the list of customers to be rendered.

Following this way all the heavy lifting (including URL resolution) will be made for you by infrastructure and you'll get your "reusable widget" or "control".

As for mentioned `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` stuff - you have to decide: you either want to use ASP.NET **routing** or build all the routes by yourself. Because these techniques are somewhat excluding each other.

P.S. Anyway, more details on what exactly you want to achieve will help us to help you.